# Split a string on a pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

```
   var a="##55##data1!!##66##data4545!!##77##data44!!";
```

how to remove ##664545##data!! from the string

Edit:if we know the start value in a string i.e,##66## and the end value ie,!!

In the main string how to remove characters starting from the start pattern,data after the start pattern till the end pattern

```
      My expected output will be ##55##data1!##77##data44!!
```

Comment: This doesn't help answer your question, but you might want to look into JSON. It's a way of transporting data as a string that avoids this kind of mess.

Comment: can be more detailed? maybe try putting **few** examples of **before/after** relationship. Things now and what is expected. Clear question will get clear answer. Promise!

Comment: what subject is this anyway? there are more of you who asked almost the same question today. ;)

Comment: @Reigel - if you can cite those, perhaps this should be closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using javascript and regex -

```
a.replace(/##66##[a-zA-Z0-9]*!!/g,"")
```

If you want to parameterize this then you can do as given below where start and end are your parameters-

```
    var a = "##55##data1!!##66##data4545!!##77##data44!!";
    var start = "##66##";
    var end = "!!";

    var re = new RegExp(start + "[a-zA-Z0-9]*" + end, "g");

    return a.replace(re,"");
```

Comment: @Sachin:if the data changes ,how is the replace to be made?

Comment: I think the question is about how to extract data item 66 from the string, regardless of what is contained in 'data'.

Comment: @Hulk - Everytime do you know what data to replace? If yes, then you can have a function for replace and pass this data as argument. Is that ok? or if you can explain in detail the situtation in your question, it would be helpful.

Comment: @Hulk you might want to edit your question and phrase it a little more clearly

Comment: @Hulk - The edited question still does not give any information on what is required. Its a bit confusing. If its about extracting data 66 from the string given, there should be a definite pattern which you need to tell us in the question from which you can extract data. Something like do you want to get all data enclosed within ## and ## or something like that.

Comment: @Hulk - Edited my answer. Please check now if this is what you are looking for. I tested this, and it gives your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Regex way, with global flag `g` to catch all matches:

```
a.replace(/##66##data!!/g,"")
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstooed the question, it is about parsing the string to get the value of 'data' for item ##66##.

Comment: if the data changes to a string say"abcdfeg"  ,how is the replace to be made?

Comment: @fredley - I don't think that's at all clear. It explicitly says removal and sounds like removal based on a dynamic value, but it could be extraction admittedly.

Comment: @Hulk - if `data` is a dynamic value you can either allow for a general match (replace data with `.*?`) or you can build a Regex dynamically on the explicit value you're looking for.